# TI SensorTag provides invalid sensor values

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, sensors, iot, texas-instruments

I bough CC2650STK, unbox and run BLE SensorTag app on my Samsung Galaxy S4 and:

- Humidity Data - 47,6%rH ([iNode Care Sensor PHT](https://inode.pl/iNode-Care-Sensor-PHT-p34) presents: 35,9%)
- Barometer Data - 843.3 mBar (S4: 982.4 mBar, iNode: 980.2 mBar)
  Ambient Temperature Data is equals +/- 0.1°C.

Why humidity and barometer have huge divergence? My SensorTag is damaged? Or it required calibration? How I can to do?

I wrote some reads in [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nOjZsUxrW7W_M-JX517BIqVZ-3aVP-oT5_yNi9Eiicg/edit?usp=sharing) and they look like they were repetitive.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

For barometer data - it is bug in apk from Google Play and not fixed yet. You must:

1. clone git repo from: https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android
2. apply path from:
   https://git.ti.com/sensortag-20-android/sensortag-20-android/merge_requests/1
3. build and install on your Android device and run :)